# How to use model attribute in both POST and GET in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am getting an attribute called **Number** using POST method. Also I have a form in my template with GET method.For that form,I need to use the **Number** but it returns None.

`views.py`

```
def recognition(request):
    tableFilter = ''

    if request.method == "POST":
        Number = request.POST.get('Number', None)
        meter = Meter.objects.get( Number= Number)

    if request.method == "GET":
         ************Here I need to use meter existing in POST part(first if)*********
        object_list = Report.objects.filter(meter=meter)
        tableFilter = RecordFilter(request.GET, queryset=object_list)

    context = {
        'meter':meter,
        'table_filter':tableFilter,

    }
    return render(request, 'services/specificMeterDelete.html',context)
```

How can I access **Number** in GET part?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the Number using form action and put it in your url.Then in the view get it by kwargs.e.g:
template:

```
<form  action="{% url 'the url you need' send it here for example obj.pk %}">
```

then make a url like :

```
path('the path.../<pk>', views.the view you need, name='the name you have for that')
```

view :

```
number = kwargs.get("pk",None)
```

Hope to be helpful.